# What causes Familiar to disappear?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Wizard skill, "Familiar", summons a small helper that helps you attack enemies and cannot be hit. There doesn't seem to be a spell duration on it (no icon indicator as far as I can tell), but I have noticed at times that it would disappear and I would have to re-cast it. Beyond the obvious situation of dying causing it to disappear, in what other situations would I have to re-summon the Familiar? Does using a Waypoint or a Town Portal cause it to disappear? Or is there an actual duration to the spell involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you not have advanced tool tips turned on?

[Familiar](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/familiar) has a duration of 5 minutes.

> Summon a companion that will attack your targets for 20% weapon damage
>   as Arcane. This companion cannot be targeted or damaged by enemies and
>   lasts for 5 minutes.

Comment: Didn't even realize that was an option. Thanks!